# How to get home page layout programmatically in controller method

Tags: layout

In my custom module I used Ajax. I want to change product count depending on the layout. How to get home page layout programmatically in controller method?

Comment: I think you have to specify your answer a bit - it's not clear what you are trying to achieve. The layout-handle of the home page is cms_index_index.

Comment: It's quite clear actually. They want to change the product count depending on the current layout.

Comment: @Matthias - i donot want layout handle of home page. I want home page layout used i.e 1columns.phtml. I working on extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by adding hidden field in the template file.

```
<!-- For layout dependent Columns -->
<?php $layoutDepColCount = $this->getLayoutDependColumnCount();?>
<?php $_columnCount = empty($layoutDepColCount) ? $this->getColumnCount() : $layoutDepColCount;?>
<input type="hidden" name="columnCount" id="columnCount" value="<?php echo $_columnCount; ?>" />
```

I passed this column count as parameter to the ajax call.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
function showFeaturedProduct(pageno){
    $j(document).ready(function(){
         //For layout dependent Columns
        var columnCount = $j('#columnCount').val();
        $j.get("featuredproduct/index/pager", {p:pageno, cols:columnCount},
        function(data,status){
           if(status == 'success') {
              // alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
               $j("#featuredproductlist").html(data);
           }
        }
        ,"html");
    });
}
```

Added new method in the block

```
/**
     * Get the layout dependent number of products.
     *
     * @return int column count
     */
    public function getLayoutDependColumnCount()
    {
        $columnCount = 0;
        $listBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('featuredproduct.list.page');
        if ($listBlock) {
            $columnCount = abs(intval($this->getRequest()->getParam('cols')));
        }
        return $columnCount;
    }
```